# how to make dill load python2 pickle in python3

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, io, pickle, dill

If pickled using `pickle` then following snippet works.  but if I have an object dumped using dill,  `dill.load` does not work because `dill.load` does not accept any `encoding` argument. is there any way to make this work using dill?

```
with open(‘py2pickle.p’,'rb') as f
    data = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did `dill.dump` in python 2, and want do do a `dill.load` in python 3.  There are two issues:

1. there's no guarantee, regardless of what you are
   using for serialization that a pickle will work with any version of
   python other than the one you used (i.e. 3.7 vs 3.6 vs 2.7).
2. <s>as you noted, currently `dill` doesn't have an encoding argument on `load`, so you may have to do some conversion before/after you `dump`/`load` the object (directly on the object itself).</s>

<s>Note that I will be adding more of the serialization option arguments to `dump` and `load` in the very near future (including the `encoding` argument).</s>

**Update:** `dill` now has an encoding argument, as well as other arguments to aid pickle conversion from 2.x to 3.x.

Comment: nope. i did `dill.dump` in python2 and want to load it in python3

Comment: I didn’t know you are the dill dev/maintainer. Thanks for the great work!!

Comment: I've just added the `encoding` argument and other more recent python 3.x arguments for reading pickles from 2.x.